# Await not resolving before continuing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to working with asynchronous functions and I have some questions about how await is supposed to work. I have the following function and I am confused by the output.

```
arrayA = []
arrayB = []
con.query('SELECT * FROM table', async function(err, result) {
  test = await 'test';
  console.log(test);
  if (err) throw err;
  n = 0;
  for (var column of Object.keys(result)) {
    arrayA[n] = await result[column].A;
    arrayB[n] = await result[column].B;
    n = n+1;
  }
});
console.log(arrayA);
```

What I expect the output to be is:

```
test
[
    "item 1"
    "item 2"
    ...
    "item n"
]
```

but what I get is:

```
[]
test
```

Given this it's clear that it is not waiting for the arrays to be populated before continuing or even for the test variable to be written. I have been looking everywhere reading about how promises and asynchronous functions work but haven't been able to resolve this so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`con.query` is asynchronous, hence the callback, so your last `console.log(arrayA)` is not going to wait for con.query (and the callback within) to finish before executing.

The order of events (in comments) is as follows:

```js
# 1
arrayA = []
# 2
arrayB = []
# 3 (the query is sent to the server, but we do not wait for a response
con.query('SELECT * FROM table', async function(err, result) {
  # 5 (await will "pause execution" for the 
  #   expression to the right, a string is not a promise so this doesn't do anything
  test = await 'test';
  # 6
  console.log(test);
  # 7
  if (err) throw err;
  # 8
  n = 0;
  # 9, 10, etc
  for (var column of Object.keys(result)) {
    # is result[column].A a promise? if not, await won't do anything.
    arrayA[n] = await result[column].A;
    arrayB[n] = await result[column].B;
    n = n+1;
  }
});
# 4 (still waiting on the server to respond, callback is "scheduled")
console.log(arrayA);
```

What you would need is to `await con.query`, but since it uses callbacks await won't work, so you would need to wrap in a promise or "promisify":

```js
(async () => {

  arrayA = []
  arrayB = []  

  // wait until resolve is called
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM table", async function (err, result) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      for (var column of Object.keys(result)) {
        arrayA[n] = result[column].A;
        arrayB[n] = result[column].B;
      }
      // you can await more things here if you need to
      // calling resolve here resolves the promise we are awaiting for con.query
      resolve();
    });
  });

  // since we awaited a promise above, con.query should be done
  console.log(arrayA);

})().catch((e) => { 
  console.error(e); 
  process.exit(1) 
});
```

Using callbacks and promises at the same time is always a bit verbose. Many libraries implement a promise interface so your could could be as simple as the below if the mysql client library you're using supported a Promise interface:

```js
const rows = await con.query("SELECT * FROM table");

rows.forEach(row => { ... });
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing two concepts here. Your SQL execution is using a callback function, which gets invoked once the query is done executing. This is not blocking (this is why you see the empty array printed immediately).

You now have defined the callback function to be `async`, which means that you can `await` other async operations in it. This `await` is then blocking, but only in the context of this execution context (function). Given that a string assignment isn't really an async operation it probably will not behave any different than a normal execution of the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways by which you can solve the issue. But this is the most convenient one.

```
var arrayA = [];
var arrayB = [];
try {
  var result = await con.query("SELECT * FROM table");
  n = 0;
  for (var column of Object.keys(result)) {
    arrayA[n] = await result[column].A;
    arrayB[n] = await result[column].B;
    n = n + 1;
  }
  console.log(arrayA);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

You can read more on this topic [here](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-async-await-6fb25b01b628)